# Adding list of different length to an array

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I am having an array were I add several lists to this array. After that I would like to add other columns to this array which do not have the same length.

```
int minSize = Math.min(testList.get(j).getDate().size(), testList.get(j).getTotalReturnIndex().size());

List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for(int m = 0; m < minSize; m++)
{
    //TODO remove .replace('.', ',')
    data.add(new String[] {testList.get(j).getCompanyName(), testList.get(j).getDate().get(m), testList.get(j).getCurrency(), testList.get(j).getTotalReturnIndex().get(m).toString().replace('.', ','), testList.get(j).getPrice().get(m).toString().replace('.', ','), "", sublist.get(m)});
    //here I am getting an `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:` because the list is not so long like the others
}
```

This is how I add the first part(the first 5 columns of the picture) to the array.

Visualized in excel my array should look like that in the end:

[image]

How to add the other 3 columns to my array beginning with `sublist` based on the above code?

I really appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it with a simple ternary:

```
int minSize = Math.min(testList.get(j).getDate().size(), testList.get(j).getTotalReturnIndex().size());

List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for(int m = 0; m < minSize; m++) {
    //TODO remove .replace('.', ',')
    data.add(new String[] {testList.get(j).getCompanyName(),
        testList.get(j).getDate().get(m), 
        testList.get(j).getCurrency(), 
        testList.get(j).getTotalReturnIndex().get(m).toString().replace('.', ','),
        testList.get(j).getPrice().get(m).toString().replace('.', ','),
        "", 
        (m < sublist.size())? sublist.get(m) : "" 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! What is better if I only have one value: `new String[]{""}` or `""` ?

Comment: it should only be "", because you only can put simple Strings in a String Array. Sorry, I was confused, because there are 3 more columns in your excel sheet. I will edit the code.